# How to use Emacs with Python

Tags: python, emacs

I am new to emacs and I want to use emacs for python development. I am using Ubuntu 9.10. I frustrated to getting emacs work with python. I use GNU Emacs 23.1.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.0).

Here what I did.
*

Emacs come with python mode but it is confusing there are two types of mode one is python-mode.el and other one is python.el.  I use emacs 23 so mine is python.el (I think). Do I need python-mode too? Code completion does not work when I press  M-Tab , instead of it window manager works. I tried Esc-Tab but it says "No match" . How can I enable code completion?

After that I installed ropemacs

```
sudo aptitude install python-ropemacs
```

Then I created .emacs file at ~/.emacs
and I added followings to .emacs file

```
(require 'pymacs)   
(pymacs-load "ropemacs" "rope-")   
(setq ropemacs-enable-autoimport t)
```

Then when I hit M-/ (Alt-/) it doesn't work when I cick from the menu Rope->Code assist  it opens a file dialog for choosing root project folder. I choose current folder which has there are some python code. When I try again Code assist from menu it says
"Completion for x: " nothing but empty set. How can make emacs python code completion work?

Then I downloaded [anything.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anything.el), anything-config, anything-match-plugin to ~/.emacs.d folder Then I added following lines to .emacs file

```
(require 'anything-config)   
(require 'anything-match-plugin)   
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'anything)   
(global-set-key "\C-ce" 'anything-for-files)
```

Guess what it didnt work. I tried "M-x anything" again I get No match.(I guessed may me combination of  C-ca (First control-a then e ) might work it says it isnt defined). Could you explain code completion for python with clear explanations (step by step)  to someone  dummy as me. Thanks. 
Edit: I able emacs work with python with the link. Thanks all for answering

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried anything, and I haven't had much luck with rope (giant source tree causes my emacs to hang upon any file save).  Instead, I find the default completion works well enough for my purposes.

The default completion keybinding is `M-/`.  That runs dabbrev-expand which expands the current word to "the most recent, preceding word for which this is a prefix."  It's not perfect: It won't parse types, and it won't search imports, but it works in 90% of the cases.

(You'll have to deactivate rope.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you *do* want the package `python-mode` installed!  The ropemacs variants appears to be for refactoring only, and pymacs is allows Python as an Emacs-extension language -- neither of which is what you need for standard support.

Comment: Now I tried following
sudo aptitude install python-mode
then I get one extra menu IM-Python and other Python menu completely changed now there is no Complete symbols

Comment: That's the way it is -- you need other emacs tools to give you code completion under Linux.  The EmacsWiki may get you started and the tools (cedet, ecb, ...) are also in Ubuntu.  That said, I don't use much beside TAGS and the 'much simpler but mostly good enough' M-/.

Comment: @TonyCruise Seems an outdated version is used. Please load a current one, development is here: https://gitlab.com/groups/python-mode-devs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure you had to do anything fancy to get Python development to work. On gNewSense deltah (fork of Ubuntu 8.04) all I did was edit a .py file with the first line being:

`#!/usr/bin/python`

And then Emacs just figures it out and gives you python mode options. I didn't have to install anything beyond Emacs.

Then again, this may not be helpful as gNewSense pre-installs Emacs by default. I'll have to do it on one of my vanilla Ubuntu installs.

Comment: Emacs activates Python mode by looking py extension but code complation does not work

Comment: I mean Python menu is visible. I tried from Menu Python->Complete symbol but didn't work.

Comment: @TonyCruise It should. Please file a bug-report at https://gitlab.com/groups/python-mode-devs/issues as it need some more info to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs worked out of the box for me on Ubuntu 9.10.

Did you try `C-c TAB` (update imports) before trying code completion?  I don't think it work unless you do that.

Comment: I typed C-c TAB . Then I write impo (I want it to comlete to import) then from menu Python-> Complete symbol  I got No match.

Comment: Yes you are right.  My fingers typed `M-/` which works, but isn't the same thing as the menu entry `Complete Symbol` which doesn't appear to work.