# Why I can't use auto-complete for python modules in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, ropemacs, rope

I have been trying to use emacs as a python IDE, I have tried many step-by-step examples to do it. But I have some trouble for function completion. Now I have auto complete (with tab completion) for local variables and snippets from yasnippets, but for some reason it is not working for modules or built in function. E.g. it is not working for string functions or os.path as shown here; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDTwuOVbAFc

note; I'm opening new rope project before trying.

I am running emacs 24.0.91 on ubuntu 11.10 and I have downloaded rope and ropemacs from ubuntu repository

```
 sudo apt-get install python-rope
 sudo apt-get install python-ropemacs
```

(I have also tried to download and install rope as suggested on [Ryan's blog](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&key=cdee124b11d6baacda6c3e29b12e23dc&loc=http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/&v=1&libid=1326560085601&out=http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/21/autocompleteel-python-code-completion-in-emacs/&ref=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862901/how-to-use-emacs-with-python&title=Setup%20Perfect%20Python%20Environment%20In%20Emacs%20%C2%AB%20The%20website%20of%20Lei%20Chen&txt=%20here&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13265686538741).)

My .init file is here; http://pastebin.com/hfS5yTXC

And when I use [this](http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/) tutorial, things get even worse, and auto complete stops running for yasnippets and local variables too.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have forked the `emacs-for-python` package which lives here;
https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python

although, there is still no tab completion with `auto-complete`, i can use rope-code-assist to complete module functions. I will update my answer if i could get it working with tab-completion.